# Dual booting with Windows 7 and Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, partition, windows, dual-boot

I am creating a dual boot system for Windows 7 & Fedora 20. While installing to hard drive I get this error **Installation destination**  `Error checking storage configuration`. I have shrunk my hard drive partition to have 30 GB of space. But the installer only shows 1.99 MB available. Now 1.99 MB is the amount of space on my Pen Drive, but the drive the installer picks is my hard drive listed as 479 GB. How do I proceed with my installation of Fedora 20?

**using Parted -l**

**output::**

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   210GB  210GB   primary   ntfs
 3      210GB   294GB  84.2GB  primary   ntfs
 4      294GB   500GB  206GB   extended               lba
 5      294GB   500GB  206GB   logical   ntfs


Model: Kingston DataTraveler G2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4011MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4129kB  4011MB  4007MB  primary  fat32        boot


Model: Linux device-mapper (snapshot) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/live-osimg-min: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/live-base: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (snapshot) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/live-rw: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  ext4
```

still problem is persist here are screen shots [DOC link](https://drive.google.com/a/eanda.co.in/file/d/0B1jKNrWC6qzaWVVLcWIzWFBFWERZU0c0VVkzRDJNdnhiUVNV/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please, paste output of `# parted -l` from LiveCD.

Comment: @enedil plz check above edited question

Comment: You haven't got any `ext` partition on your hard drive.

Comment: @enedil So how best to proceed? I do not know what an `ext` partition is. In the past we have successfully installed Fedora 11 on a dual boot Windows machine. It automatically picked the free space and installed there.

Comment: You don't have any free space. You must manually shrink a `NTFS` partition or delete one.

Comment: @enedil can you please guide me for further as m new bie ...Linux detected tht free unallocated space ..now how to reclaim tht disk space for further installation?

Comment: Please tell us, which partition can you shrink/delete.

Comment: 4 ..     294GB   500GB  206GB   extended               lba

Comment: During the installation process, are you selecting the 'automatically configure my Fedora installation to the disks...' option or 'I want to review/modify my disk partitions before continuing' option? I would recommend you modify your partitions manually instead of using the automatic option.

Comment: @Chirag64 yes m creating them manually

Answer (score 1):

4 is your extended partition. I believe you wish to delete your logical partition which is the 5th one.

You'll need to format it to an `ext` partition as @enedil mentioned in order to install Fedora on it.

Before following these below steps, make sure you've taken a backup of your critical data, because these tools can delete wrong partitions if the correct partition number isn't specified.

1. Boot from a Live CD and open the terminal as root.
2. Once you've done that, you can run `cfdisk` or `fdisk` tool to [delete and create a Linux partition](http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/) on /dev/sda5 (assuming you wish to use the 5th partition).
3. After that, you can format the partition using the `mkfs.ext4` tool.
4. You can check if the changes made have been correctly implemented by running `fdisk -l`.
5. Once your partition is ready, you can start the Fedora installation again and select the appropriate partition for installation.

Comment: please chek doc file edited in question